# Scraping Webpage With Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, json, selenium, screen-scraping

I am new to web scraping and I am trying to scrape wind data from a website. Here is the website: https://wx.ikitesurf.com/spot/507.
I understand that I can do this using selenium to find elements but I think I may have found a better way. Please correct if I am wrong. When in developer tools I can find this page by going to network->JS->getGraph?

https://api.weatherflow.com/wxengine/rest/graph/getGraph?callback=jQuery17200020271765600428093_1619158293267&units_wind=mph&units_temp=f&units_distance=mi&fields=wind&format=json&null_ob_min_from_now=60&show_virtual_obs=true&spot_id=507&time_start_offset_hours=-36&time_end_offset_hours=0&type=dataonly&model_ids=-101&wf_token=3a648ec44797cbf12aca8ebc6c538868&_=1619158293881

This page contains all the data I need and it is constantly updating. Here is my code:

```
url = 'https://api.weatherflow.com/wxengine/rest/graph/getGraph?callback=jQuery17200020271765600428093_1619158293267&units_wind=mph&units_temp=f&units_distance=mi&fields=wind&format=json&null_ob_min_from_now=60&show_virtual_obs=true&spot_id=507&time_start_offset_hours=-36&time_end_offset_hours=0&type=dataonly&model_ids=-101&wf_token=3a648ec44797cbf12aca8ebc6c538868&_=1619158293881'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
time.sleep(3)
wind = soup.find("last_ob_wind_desc")
print (wind)
```

I tried using beautiful soup to scrape but I always receive the answer "None". Does anyone know how I can scrape this page? I would like to know what I am doing wrong. Thanks for any help!

Comment: The problem is that the response is not html. The content-type is `application/x-javascript` so you should use another parser or library to read the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing `callback=jQuery17200020271765600428093_1619158293267&` from the `api` url will make it return proper json:

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.weatherflow.com/wxengine/rest/graph/getGraph?units_wind=mph&units_temp=f&units_distance=mi&fields=wind&format=json&null_ob_min_from_now=60&show_virtual_obs=true&spot_id=507&time_start_offset_hours=-36&time_end_offset_hours=0&type=dataonly&model_ids=-101&wf_token=3a648ec44797cbf12aca8ebc6c538868&_=1619158293881'
response = requests.get(url).json()
```

`response` is now a dictionary with the data. `last_ob_wind_desc` can be retrieved with `response['last_ob_wind_desc']`.

You can also save the data to `csv` or other file formats with `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.json_normalize(response)
df.to_csv('filename.csv')
```

Comment: Exactly ! I am agreed with your approach .

Comment: Worked! I have been trying to figure this out using selenium for a week but this is so much better. I really appreciate the help.